# How to access $toast in pinia Store? any Example Please

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, toast, pinia

I am using **Vue 3** option API, **Pinia**, and vue-toaster  or $swal.

I have imported the toaster in main.js as the document said and it works perfectly in components
now I need to use it in Pinia Store.

after Axios success or error.

Note : if it's wrong to use axios and toaster or any lib in store. so what the best way.
please with example .

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far?

Comment: "if it's wrong to use axios and toaster or any lib in store" - it's not wrong. You probably shouldn't use $axios, $swal, etc global comp props as they aren't really specific to Vue. They are the legacy of non-modular Vue that were exposed on Vue.prototype for convenience. If there's global toast service, it needs to be defined in some module and imported wherever you use it